# Is there any way to LOOP THROUGH all cells of a range by using LAMBDA in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to loop through all cells of a range and merge them .

For example, If i have data in the range C2: C9:
[image]

How can i loop from C2 to C9 by using LAMBDA in Excel?

I've tried to use recursion of LAMBDA but it did not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: I hope to find the unique value of a range; in my example, I hope the result is 4 because it only shows up once!

Comment: But 2 also appears only once?

Comment: Oh, my fault, yes, i hope the result will return 2 and 4 sir!.

Comment: Then you don't need a `LAMBDA`; simply `=UNIQUE(C2:C9,,1)`

Comment: I know UNIQUE formula, but I would like to know how LAMBDA works when looping through a range, sir. So I can use it for many different purposes.

Comment: Then do some research on functions such as `BYROW`.

Comment: Using a `LAMBDA()` means using an iterative process. For example: `=LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(C2:C9,x))(C2:C9)` would find that the values 2 and 4 only occur once. You could then apply a `FILTER()` or so to end up with these values. You could also use ms pre-build lambda helpers like `REDUCE()` to build an array iteratively. It goes without saying that both these techniques are not necessary for the sample you provide since `=FILTER(C2:C9,COUNTIF(C2:C9,C2:C9)=1)` would do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an entire solution, but using this formula in a helper column, you might get what you are looking for:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C$9,C2)=1,"Found", "Not")
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image]